# Conflicting versions of adapter-transformers with versions of tokenizers

Tags: python, pip, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to install adapter-transformers=3.1.0, then it give following error. How could I find the compatible adapter-transformers version for tokenizers==0.9.2?

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> transformers 3.4.0 requires tokenizers==0.9.2, but you have tokenizers 0.13.2 which is incompatible.

Comment: You already have tokenizers 0.13.2 installed. Try to install `tokenizers==0.9.2`.

Comment: transformers 3.4.0 requires tokenizers==0.9.2, but you have tokenizers 0.13.2 which is incompatible.

Comment: That may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/77733975/18963373