# Can't import AdapterTrainer

Tags: python, pip, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying text classification with adapters in google colab and faced a lot of problems with libs.

```
!pip install -U adapter-transformers 

from transformers import TrainingArguments, AdapterTrainer, EvalPrediction
```

gives an error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.adapters.trainer because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import transformers.trainer_seq2seq because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'default_hp_search_backend' from 'transformers.integrations' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/integrations/__init__.py)
```

Most confusing part is that I already ran this notebook earlier.

I've tried a lot of manipulations with libraries:

installed using git, deleted and installed different parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably already have `transformers` installed. `adapter-transformers`⚠️ is a fork of the `transformers` library and can't be installed in the same environment:

> `adapter-transformers` is a direct fork of `transformers`. This means our package includes all the awesome features of HuggingFace’s original package, plus the adapter implementation. As both packages share the same namespace, they ideally should not be installed in the same environment.

**Note**: The `adapter-transformers` package is deprecated and replaced by the `adapters` package. Install it using :

```
pip install adapters
```

You need to import the `AdapterTrainer` from `adapters` instead of `transformers` ([transitioning](https://docs.adapterhub.ml/transitioning.html#transitioning-from-adapter-transformers)) :

```py
from transformers import TrainingArguments, EvalPrediction
from  adapters import AdapterTrainer
```

See see [here](https://adapterhub.ml/blog/2023/11/introducing-adapters/) for more informations.